# How do i make sure ALL textfields & Radio Buttons are selected inside a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with textfield, textareas and radio buttons. I want to make sure everything inside the div is selected, therefore i have disabled the submit button until everything is selected. But i can't seem to get it to work. I have a jquery functions which works, when i check on all the required input fields, but it doesn't work on radio buttons. Here is what is working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  function checkInputs() {
    var validInputs = true;
    $('input').filter('[required]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        validInputs = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if(validInputs) {$('#speichern').prop('disabled', false)}
    return validInputs;
  }

  //Enable or disable button based on if inputs are filled or not
  $('input').filter('[required]').on('keyup',function() {
    checkInputs();
  })

  checkInputs();

});
```

How can i include the radio buttons inside this function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside `checkInputs()`

```
$('input').filter('[required]').each(function() {
  var elm = this,
    $elm = $(elm);
  switch (elm.type) {
    case 'text':
      if ($elm.val() === '') {
        validInputs = false;
        return false;
      }
      break;
    case 'radio':
      if (!elm.checked) {
        validInputs = false;
        return false;
      }
      break;
    case 'checkbox':
      // handle checkbox
      break;
    default:
      // handle others
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: it seems to work, but the "if(validInputs) {$('#speichern').prop('disabled', false)}" part doesn't work. The Button doesn't enable